# Converting JSON dates in a DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, datatable

I have a DataTable that's populated by dates that appear like this: `"/Date(1523260800000)/"`, and I want them to appear like: `January 1, 2000`.

I have a snippet that *does* work in a different area of my code, but when I try to integrate it into DataTables it doesn't work. Something about returning JSON nodes + functions and the whole thing goes batty.

#### JS snippet:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import admissData from '../JSON/admiss.json';
import DataTable from 'datatables.net';

function loadAdmiss() {
    let admissText = admissData.d.results.map(function(val) {
        return {
            "Info": val.info,
            "Date of Admission": val.dateofadmission, function() { // ----- this code block works elsewhere
                let jsonDate = val.dateofadmission;
                let value = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, ''))
                );
                let dat = value.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + value.getDate() + "/" + value.getFullYear();
                return dat;
            },
            "Expires": val.expires
        }
    })
```

#### Rendering DataTable:

```
    $('#admissions-table').DataTable({
            columns: [
                { data: "Info" },
                { data: "Date of Admission" },
                { data: "Expires" }
            ],
            data: admissText,
            ...
```

#### JSON snippet:

```
{
    "d": {
      "results": [
        {
         ...
          "dateofadmission": "/Date(1523260800000)/",
           ...
           ...
```

Comment: I don't think this will answer your question but have you tried datatables [renderers](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers)? So, instead of using map to change your data after you fetch, you just put it in individual column's render function.

Comment: @PriyankPanchal I have used renderers before. I'll take a look and see what I can do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in order to convert this "/Date(1523260800000)/" this January 1, 2000

1) `var f=str.split("(")[1]; // split ( an get the second value the number`

2)`var s=f.split(")")[0]` // split the other )

3)`var d= new date(ParseInt(s))` //now you got your date ,remember to parse